# Why Drupal 7 takes too time in connecting to mysql db? - measured with xdebugger

Tags: performance, database

i have drupal 7 on localhost (core i7 - 12gb ram etc)
on Nginx with APC and mySql on windows7.

standard installation with standard theme and a bounch of new modules. about NO content.

The problem is that the homepage take ever 1,5 sec to load (without APC 3 secs).
i installed XDEBUGGER and with winCacheGrind i discovered that 75% of the time is lost in DB connections. Self: 2ms, Cumulative:1007ms 
[image: screenshot of the winCacheGrind]

i tried almost anything i found on google... also i ported db engine to MyISAM... mySql is configured with my-HUGE.ini file... so it can take any resource from the computer.

How could i solve this?

1,5sec for any loggedin user is too much time... on the hosting this time will be greater as i won't have a so big dedicated server...

Comment: try checking the reverse DNS problem, noted here for example http://lists.mysql.com/win32/17156

Comment: i probably misunderstood your situation - the above note is especially valid for situations where mysql is on a different server ...

Comment: yes, my DB is on the same server of NGINX (localhost)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good group for you to join on groups.drupal.org
http://groups.drupal.org/drupal-windows

Looking at this post it sounds like the issue you are describing: http://groups.drupal.org/node/242443.

> Make sure that your Drupal settings.php connection string uses the IP
>   address of your MySQL server (e.g. 127.0.0.1 for your local Windows
>   machine), not 'localhost'.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! Can't understand why i haven't found that post before!

Page load time decreaset very much! Homepage (in admin mode) take now 235ms - A very good improvement!

I will test other behaviour!

Comment: @mikeytown2 I merely thought it was worth mention that the localhost to 127.0.0.1 switch should only apply on a Windows machine, on Linux using 'localhost' would use Unix sockets which are more performant than going through the network stack. (I'm aware that you are likely aware of it, but it may not be clear to all users.)

Comment: You need to specify unix_socket even on Linux http://www.reddit.com/r/drupal/comments/2e6h9j/we_sped_up_the_site_with_a_simple_settingsphp/